# Efficiently assigning UUIDs to connected components in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-algorithm

I have partitioned my graph into ~400,000 connected components using the algo.unionFind function from the Neo4j Graph Algorithms library.

Each node n within the same connected component has the same n.partition value. However, now I want to assigned each connected component a UUID so that each node n in a connected component will have n.uuid populated with a component UUID. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Currently I am getting a list of all n.partition values and then going through each partition and running a Cypher query to update all nodes of that partition to have a generated UUID. I'm using the Python wrapper py2neo and this process is quite slow.

Edit:

The Cypher queries I am currently using are:

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN DISTINCT n.partition AS partition
```

to get a list of partitions ids and then iteratively calling:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.partition = <PARTITION_ID>
SET n.uuid = <GENERATED_UUID>
```

on each of the partition ids.

Edit 2:
I am able to get through ~180k/400k of the connected components using the following query:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (n)
WITH n.partition as partition, COLLECT(n) as nodes
RETURN partition, nodes, apoc.create.uuid() as uuid",
"FOREACH (n in nodes | SET n.uuid = uuid)",
{batchSize:1000, parallel:true}
)
```

before getting a heap error: `` "neo4j.exceptions.ClientError: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" ``

Comment: Can you provide the queries you're attempting? And just to make sure I understand, per distinct partition value, you want to generate a UUID, and use that same UUID on all of the nodes with that partition value?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have updated my question to include the queries I'm making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to [install the APOC plug-in](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_installation_with_neo4j_desktop) to Neo4j so that you can use the UUID [function](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_node_functions) `apoc.create.uuid()` in Cypher. (so that it can be generated, and assigned, in the same transaction)

To create 1 uuid per partition, you will need to use WITH to store the uuid in a temporary variable. It will be run per row, so you need to do it once you have one partition

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000 // commit every 5k changes
MATCH (n)
WITH DISTINCT n.partition as p // will exclude null
WITH p, apoc.create.uuid() as uuid // create reusable uuid
// now just match and assign
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.partition = p
SET n.uuid = uuid
```

or as InverseFalcon suggested

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE exists(n.partition) // to filter out nulls
WITH n.partition as p, collect(n) as nodes // collect nodes so each row is 1 partition, and it's nodes
WITH p, nodes, apoc.create.uuid() as uuid // create reusable uuid
FOREACH (n in nodes | SET n.uuid = uuid) // assign uuid to each node in collection
```

The first query is more periodic commit friendly, since it doesn't need to load everything into memory to start doing assignments. Without the perodic commit statement though, it will eventually load everything into memory as it has to hold on to it for the transaction log. Once it hits a commit point, it can clear the transaction log to keep memory use down.

If your data set isn't too large though, the second query should be faster because by holding everything in memory after the first node scan, it doesn't need to run another node scan to find all the nodes. Periodic commit won't help here because if you blow the heap, it will almost certainly be during the initial scan/collect phase.

Comment: Awesome, did not know about this function before, thanks. The algo.unionFind function doesn't seem to allow for writing out custom partition ids. Is there a way to write a single Cypher query that can group nodes by partition and then, per partition, write a uuid generated by apoc.create_uuid to all nodes within the partition?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out the periodic commit query.

Comment: @K23 I work on the graph algos library and am curious why you prefer to use a UUID for the partition rather than the numeric value that the library sets? If there's a general reason why that's preferable we could try and make it configurable.

Comment: @MarkNeedham Mainly just a personal preference. One slight benefit would be the fact that I want to keep the same UUIDs over time and if I used the partition number, new connected components in the future would be assigned a higher partition number (a property I would like to keep less visible through the ID).

Answer (score 1):

To do this you'll need to collect nodes by their partition value, which means you'll have a single row per distinct partition. Then you create the UUID (it will execute per row), then you can use FOREACH to apply to each node in the partition:

```
MATCH (n)
// WHERE exists(n.partition) // only if there are nodes in the graph without partitions
WITH n.partition as partition, collect(n) as nodes
WITH partition, nodes, randomUUID() as uuid
FOREACH (n in nodes | SET n.uuid = uuid)
```

Depending on the number of nodes in your graph, you may need to combine this with some batch processing, such as `apoc.periodic.iterate()`, to avoid heap issues.

Comment: I updated my answer to cover the cypher as well. I'm not too familiar with `apoc.periodic.iterate()`, but it looks like it would favor UNWIND to FOREACH (depending on partition sizes). Also, because of transaction memory, do you need to use PERIODIC COMMIT with apoc iterate? or does apoc iterate break up the transaction as well?

Comment: apoc.periodic.iterate() automatically batches the transactions, you can use the `batchSize` config param to control that. That will take the batch size of results from the streaming outer query, unwind that batch, and then apply the inner query to the batch.

Comment: Just attempted this query combined with apoc.periodic.iterate(). I got through ~180k/400k of the connected components before getting a heap error: ```"neo4j.exceptions.ClientError: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"```. Any suggestions? I added the query I'm using as an edit to the question.